Powershell can not run Connect-AzAccount when opening the Powershell "as different user"
I have a very strange problem which I cant wrap my head around.
I have a host with PowerShell 5.1 installed.
When I run the PowerShell "regulary" with the user logged in to Windows I can use the Connect-AzAccount command:
Command working
When I open the Powershell location and then select "run as different user" and login to the pwoershell with a different user the command does not work. Everytime I run Connect-AzAccount the command start but fails to open the login window returning the following error:
Command fails
Then the PowerShell session freezes and i need to close it with TaskManager.
I ran $PSVersionTable in both Powershell sessions and it is the same in both sessions:
PSVersion
I'm at a complete loss whats the issue here.
Did any of you guys experience something like this before?

someone experienced this earlier, see: How to prevent error "WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'tenantid'" when running Powershell scripts in Azure

Are you running it as an administrator. @theTPH

Found a solution. Downgraded from Az.Accounts v. 3.0.0 to 2.19.0. With the older version everything works as expected.

This is a very transient issue and can be occurred due to the following reasons.
Firstly, check your  execution policies  which might block the script execution in the PowerShell. Set your execution policy to remote signed or set it as unrestricted and try it.
Use below to remove the context cache and try logging again into a different account.
 Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser
 set-Azcontext -Subscription "xxxxx" #Account B subscription


Check if there any other profiles existed in your current PowerShell environment as shown in the below way.

Update Az PowerShell modules using Update-Module -Name Az if required and make sure that it is set to the latest releases.
There are also some other ways for logging into the Azure with connect-AzAccount.
When I tried to login after clearing the cache context, it worked as expected.


You can use Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication as it doesn't require to provide any credential.



Use below command to login into the subscription directly with the help of -Subscription parameter.

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "xxxx" -Subscription "xxxxx"


Alternatively, create an application ID and a client Secret (Service Principal) under Microsoft Entra ID and use it along with the connection command as shown below.

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId xxxx -Credential $Credential

Also refer this SO by @Luuk for relevant issue.
Update:

I have faced the same error in my current PS environment now and you can also try the below workaround which worked for me.
az account get-access-token 
$conv = $token | convertfrom-json
$logtoken=$conv.accessToken
Connect-AzAccount -AccessToken $logtoken



Hi, first of all thanks for all the input.

Restriction Policy is set to Unrestricted
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser did not help
Checked for additional Powershell Profiles, there where none
I checked the module version and they are up to date
Regarding the other sign in options:


Unfortunately gave me errors when using with the microsoft supplied script Im using but maybe I can figure something out there
tested did not work
Unfortunately i need to use this user and cant use a service principal

Any other good ideas? :)

Can you try with the credential object once? @theTPH

Provide $Credential = Get-Credential, pass the username and password and then connect with Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential. @theTPH

Already tried: Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $SubscriptionId -Credential $Credential unfortunately an interactive login is required in the tenant for this user and I cant get approval to change that

Can you give Get-credential command once and check what it is showing? @theTPH

I have another approach above. Please check. @theTPH
